# Use javascript object containing functions as string in nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I am having some issue using a js object received as string in a variable and use it in nashorn.

Example:

```
string_obj = '{ title: "book", content: function () { return "123"; } }'
```

I want to load that string so that I can use it as a standard object.

For example, I want to do this but having my object as string.

```
/*
var obj = { title: "book",
        content: function () { 
           return "123";
        }
};
*/
var obj = convert_my_string_to_object(string_obj); //how to do that?
var output = Writer.load(param1, obj);
```

Eval is not working, I am getting an exception as such :

```
javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: <eval>#582:8<eval>:1:20 Expected ; but found :
```

Any idea?

Comment: Explanation in linked duplicate; better option than `eval('(' + string_obj + ')')` is `new Function('return ' + string_obj)()`; receiving JS code as strings is unusual, consider whether there’s a better approach. (Impossible to advise for sure without knowing the purpose.)

Comment: Awesome, it is working. For the code in string, I have no choice because the system behind is using strings only to pass data over.